# Swipe in which direction to get to the next newest article?

Tags: mobile, navigation, ipad, swipe

I'm working on iPad and mobile app and want to add the option to swipe the article to get the next one.
In order to get newer article what should be the direction of the swipe?

Comment: Left. When reach to the latest (newest) article, it should either say/denote that this is the latest article. Or simple take the user to the category listing page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we read from left to right this means the most natural way of swiping would to bring in new content from the right. So the comment above is correct. Swipe to the left.

updated

by 'we' I mean the West. For other languages will be in accordance with the reading direction.

Comment: To be pedantic, the direction should be reversed for RTL locales. +1

Comment: I was thinking what about Mandarin where you read top to bottom. lol

Comment: Do you think the swipe direction related to the language? isn't it universal like the back button? i'm asking because my app is in Hebrew which is written right to left.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly disagree with swiping from left to right being "natural". Natural swiping is dependent on the language, as the gesture of swiping mimics turning a page in a physical book, magazine or newspaper. So the natural direction of swiping is whatever direction you would use with printed material. Swiping left to right is intuitive for most Western locales, but I would call any application expecting such swipes with an Arabic or Hebrew locale to be counter-intuitive.

To support this assertion, I refer to the well-established practice of desktop applications "inverting" the layout in RTL locales. For example, in a Hebrew version of MS Windows, the start button is in the lower right corner, windows have their scrollbars on the left side, and toolbars or menu bars start from the right side of the screen. Such placement mirrors how a Hebrew speaker naturally reads.